# Threading issues when using HttpClient for asynchronous file downloads

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

This question is a follow-up to [Using HttpClient for Asynchronous File downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871974/using-httpclient-for-asynchronous-file-downloads).

2015/01/15 Edited to add in accomodation for multithreading - still have a mystery,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestHttpClient2
{
  class Program
  {
    /* Use Yahoo portal to access quotes for stocks - perform asynchronous operations. */

    static string baseUrl = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/";
    static string requestUrlFormat = "/table.csv?s={0}&d=0&e=1&f=2016&g=d&a=0&b=1&c=1901&ignore=.csv";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var activeTaskList = new List<Task>();

      string outputDirectory = "StockQuotes";
      if (!Directory.Exists(outputDirectory))
      {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
      }

      while (true)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:");
        string symbol = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(symbol))
        {
          break;
        }

        Task downloadTask = DownloadDataForStockAsync(outputDirectory, symbol);
        if (TaskIsActive(downloadTask))
        {
          // This is an asynchronous world - lock the list before updating it!
          lock (activeTaskList)
          {
            activeTaskList.Add(downloadTask);
          }

        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("task completed already?!??!?");
        }
        CleanupTasks(activeTaskList);
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up");
      while (CleanupTasks(activeTaskList))
      {
        Task.Delay(1).Wait();
      }
    }

    private static bool CleanupTasks(List<Task> activeTaskList)
    {
      // reverse loop to allow list item deletions
      // This is an asynchronous world - lock the list before updating it!
      lock (activeTaskList)
      {
        for (int i = activeTaskList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          if (!TaskIsActive(activeTaskList[i]))
          {
            activeTaskList.RemoveAt(i);
          }
        }
        return activeTaskList.Count > 0;
      }
    }

    private static bool TaskIsActive(Task task)
    {
      return task != null
          && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled
          && task.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted
          && task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion;
    }

    static async Task DownloadDataForStockAsync(string outputDirectory, string symbol)
    {
      try
      {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
          client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
          string requestUrl = string.Format(requestUrlFormat, symbol);

          var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
          var sendTask = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
          var response = await sendTask;
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          var httpStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

          string timestampedName = FormatTimestampedString(symbol, true);
          var filePath = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, timestampedName + ".csv");
          using (var fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
          using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpStream))
          {
            await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception on thread: {0}: {1}\r\n",
          System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
          ex.Message,
          ex.StackTrace);
      }
    }

    static volatile string lastTimestampedString = string.Empty;
    static volatile string dummy = string.Empty;
    static HashSet<string> oldStrings = new HashSet<string>();

    static string FormatTimestampedString(string message, bool uniquify = false)
    {
      // This is an asynchronous world - lock the shared resource before using it!
      //lock (dummy)
      lock (lastTimestampedString)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("IN  - Thread: {0:D2} lastTimestampedString: {1}", 
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            lastTimestampedString);

        string newTimestampedString;

        while (true)
        {
          DateTime lastDateTime = DateTime.Now;

          newTimestampedString = string.Format(
              "{1:D4}_{2:D2}_{3:D2}_{4:D2}_{5:D2}_{6:D2}_{7:D3}_{0}",
                message,
                lastDateTime.Year, lastDateTime.Month, lastDateTime.Day,
                lastDateTime.Hour, lastDateTime.Minute, lastDateTime.Second,
                lastDateTime.Millisecond
                );
          if (!uniquify)
          {
            break;
          }
          if (newTimestampedString != lastTimestampedString)
          {
            break;
          }

          //Task.Delay(1).Wait();
        };

        lastTimestampedString = newTimestampedString;
        Console.WriteLine("OUT - Thread: {0:D2} lastTimestampedString: {1}",
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            lastTimestampedString);

        if (uniquify)
        {
          oldStrings.Add(lastTimestampedString);
        }
        return lastTimestampedString;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Q) Why am I getting this intermittent error (at the end of this output.) (I am copying a long list of repeated lines of "NES" to the clipboard and pasting into the console in order to duplicate the problem):

```
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
NES
Enter symbol or [ENTER] to exit:
IN  - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString:
OUT - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_472_NES
IN  - Thread: 17 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_472_NES
OUT - Thread: 17 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_473_NES
IN  - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_473_NES
OUT - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_493_NES
IN  - Thread: 16 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_493_NES
OUT - Thread: 16 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_494_NES
IN  - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_494_NES
OUT - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_495_NES
IN  - Thread: 17 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_495_NES
IN  - Thread: 16 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_495_NES
OUT - Thread: 17 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_496_NES
IN  - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_495_NES
OUT - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_496_NES
IN  - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_496_NES
OUT - Thread: 16 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_495_NES
OUT - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_497_NES
IN  - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_497_NES
OUT - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_523_NES
IN  - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_523_NES
OUT - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_532_NES
IN  - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_532_NES
OUT - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_533_NES
IN  - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_533_NES
Exception on thread: 17: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\drogers\_code\Tests\TestHttpClient\TestHttpClient2\bin\Debug\StockQuot
es\2015_01_15_11_19_44_495_NES.csv' because it is being used by another process.

Exception on thread: 16: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\drogers\_code\Tests\TestHttpClient\TestHttpClient2\bin\Debug\StockQuot
es\2015_01_15_11_19_44_496_NES.csv' because it is being used by another process.

OUT - Thread: 18 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_540_NES
IN  - Thread: 17 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_540_NES
IN  - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_540_NES
OUT - Thread: 17 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_557_NES
OUT - Thread: 19 lastTimestampedString: 2015_01_15_11_19_44_560_NES
Exception on thread: 19: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\drogers\_code\Tests\TestHttpClient\TestHttpClient2\bin\Debug\StockQuot
es\2015_01_15_11_19_44_560_NES.csv' because it is being used by another process.
```

I can avoid the problem with the uncommenting of line 126 and commenting line 127, as in:

```
  // This is an asynchronous world - lock the shared resource before using it!
  lock (dummy)
  //lock (lastTimestampedString)
```

Looking at the il, the only difference in the code generated for FormatTimestampedString is

```
ldsfld     string modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile)
            TestHttpClient2.Program::**lastTimestampedString**
```

versus

```
ldsfld     string modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile) 
            TestHttpClient2.Program::**dummy**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable. So when I set my lock on the lastTimestampedString reference, and then changed it, I no longer had the lock I thought I had. The lock was on the old string. Anyone else coming along would be testing the lock on the new string, and would therefore be allowed in.

Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 tasks trying to write the stock data to the same file.

Change `FormatTimestampedString` to check for the existence of the generate filename and if exists generate a new one.

Comment: Or even, just don't write the file if the exception occurs. It seems unlikely that it's actually useful to write data with the same exact timestamp, right down to the milliseconds, more than once. You can probably just skip writing the file again if one with the same name already exists. Caveat: you can't call `File.Exists()` to test for this; you have to actually try to create the file, and catch an exception if it occurs. Consider using `FileStream` directly, with `FileMode.CreateNew`, to make it simpler to distinguish between a reportable exception and the file simply existing already.

Comment: The point is to avoid creating duplicate resource names based on the chosen naming algorithm.